# Каким образом можно связать сервер на Spring с Android-приложением?

Tags: java, android, spring

Я новичок в Spring поэтому такой вот вопрос.
Задача поставлена так. Есть сервер который производит обработку запросов, есть клиент на Android который отправляет запросы, и получает обработанные ответы. Сумел на гуглить Rest но ума не приложу как использовать его. И вообще возможно ли использовать REST?

Comment: да, при помощи REST можно. Чтобы это сделать, вам нужно всего-ничего - прочитать пару книг, или просмотреть пару курсов видеоуроков.  Как вы можете догадаться, тут вам эти уроки никто проводить не будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут так просто не ответить. Недавно писал клиент-сервер для курсача. Там и Spring, и JPA, и Hibernate использовал. Плюс еще JDBC. Смотри spring.io, habrahabr.ru.
На стороне андроида я использовал http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/, на сервере http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/. И на youtube посмотри, там есть русскоязычные уроки по этой теме(сейчас ссылок уже не найду).